# flash cs6 - hide word suggestion in android

Tags: actionscript-3, android-softkeyboard

I'm using flash cs6 and I need to disable word suggestions, while using softkeyboard via stageText.

I had a try with CONTACT softkeyboard type, however itisn't working as I expected.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation in the LiveDocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StageText.html) for `StageText` seems to either be missing or incomplete, but off the top of my head you need to set `StageText.autoCorrect` to false. I do remember it wasn't supported by all devices/versions, though, but I do know it has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Thanks Josh, unfrotunately that didn't helped a lot (suggestions are still showing).

Do you happen to know any other method for doing this?

Comment: No, `autoCorrect` is _the_ property for this. Could it possibly be the keyboard you are using? There's no guarantee all features will work with all keyboards, obviously.

Comment: I just did some testing and it appears it does not work for me either. Tested using stock Android keyboard, SwiftKey, and Swype on 4.2.2. My guess is Android doesn't support this. Per the docs: "This property is only a hint to the underlying platform, because not all devices and operating systems support this functionality."

Comment: Thanks Josh, I will try to "hack" the compiled apk file, seems that some settings in a manifest.xml file might work.